# Как рандомно заменить букву у элемента списка?

Tags: python

Применив метод `random.choice()` для списка с одним элементом`['qwerty']`, как заменить рандомную букву на цифру?

Comment: Надо заменить рандомную букву в слове(`qwerty`) из одноэлементного списка? Или все же заменить рандомный элемент в списке?

Comment: Рандомную букву в слове 'qwerty' из одноэлементного списка заменить на цифру или любой другой символ.

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, вашу задачу можно разбить на мелкие задачи:

1. Как обратиться к элементу списка

Ответ: Обратиться к элементу по индексу. `lst[0]` вернет ваше слово.

2. Как заменить случайную букву в слове

Ответ: `string.replace(symbol1, symbol2)` заменит в строке `string` все вхождения `symbol` на `symbol2`

3. Как получить рандомную букву в строке используя random.choice()

Ответ: передать в метод строку. `random.choice(string)` вернет случайны элемент из `string`

Итогом будет:

```
import random
lst = ['qwerty']
lst[0] = lst[0].replace(random.choice(lst[0]), str(random.randint(0, 9)))
print(lst)

>> ['qwer8y']
```